# I am using in app browser in ionic . Its opening the url on the mobile browser instead of app

Tags: ionic-framework, android-webview, ionic4, ionic-native

I am using in app browser in ionic to implement my web in app.Its working fine but its opening the url on mobile browser instead of opening it on mobile app. I am using this in my .ts file

```
ngOnInit(){
this.iab.create('url','_self','location=no');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So adding `_self`:  Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.

So you need to have `_blank` instead.
Following should work as expected.

`this.iab.create('url','_blank','location=no');`

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#cordovainappbrowseropen)